# pacman could not find database

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I want to install `sudo`. So I type in `pacman -S sudo`. But then I get the following errors:

```
warning: database file for 'extra' does not exist
warning: database file for 'community' does not exist
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not find database)
```

How do I install the database files for `'extra'` and `'community'`? I am in Arch Linux.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Firstly, try running `pacman -Syy`, then try to install sudo again.

**Check that the repositories are uncommented in `/etc/pacman.conf`.**

Or your mirrorlist might be outdated: [Generate a current list of mirrors](http://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/) and copy it to `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`

Quoting from [this relevant forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=136596):

> You can:
>
> - pick another mirror
> - try using an http mirror, not an ftp one (pick http mirror from the    mirrorlist).
> - Alternatively you can manually download the databases with:
>
>   ```
>   wget ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/archlinux/community/os/x86_64/community.db
>   wget ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/archlinux/extra/os/x86_64/extra.db
>   ```
>
>   move them to /var/lib/pacman/sync/ and run 'pacman -Syu' again.   If
>     you find any *.part files in /var/lib/pacman/sync/ e.g.
>     /var/lib/pacman/sync/core.db.part - remove them.

To prevent having problems like these it is critical to understand pacman. To learn more about using pacman, see the [ArchWiki pacman article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman), and consult `man pacman`.